# Magento 2 add custom discount before cart rule discount in checkout

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales-rule

Here we add custom discount but here the problem is I want a custom discount to calculate before a cart rule.
But here first calculate cart rule then my custom discount.

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried?

Comment: I want a custom discount to calculate or add before the cart rule discount.

Comment: Do you using any 3party extension?

Comment: Using Magento Open source version?

Comment: yes we use Mirasvit Rewards reward discount.

Comment: You can do it via cart discount so at that time your reward point is not calculated at all.